# Drop duplicate rows from a dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe with some duplicate rows (by two columns, t1 and t2), but I only want to keep one row for each duplicate, the one with the lowest value, calculated from three other columns: n, m and c

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
   "t1": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
   "t2": [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4],
   "x": [1.01, 0.66, 1.01, 0.45, 0.89, 0.64],
   "y": [0.23, 0.31, 0.06, 1.12, 0.70, 0.60],
   "z": [0.06, 1.07, 0.12, 0.20, 0.62, 0.68],
   "n": [6, 6, 7, 6, 7, 7],
   "m": [0.21, 1.19, 0.81, 1.18, 0.28, 0.67],
   "c": [64.4, 64.4, 63.2, 65.6, 63.2, 63.2]
})
```

[image]

The rows (indexes) 1 and 2 are duplicates, as well as rows 4 and 5, and when doing

```
w = (12/df['n'])*0.4 + (df['m']/0.35)*0.2 + (df['c']/150)*0.4
```

for each duplicate, I want to keep the row with the lowest `w` (se result below).

[image]

I can drop the desired rows, with this code, which gives me this final df above.

```
# adding a column with temporary values
df['w'] = (12/df['n'])*0.4 + (df['m']/0.35)*0.2 + (df['c']/150)*0.4

# create a df with the duplicated rows
dfd = df[df.duplicated(['t1', 't2'], keep=False) == True]

# initializing a list with rows (indexes) to drop
rows_to_drop = []

# groupby returns a group (g) and df (dfg)
for g, dfg in df.groupby(['t1', 't2']):
    # only groups with two or more rows
    if len(dfg) > 1:
        # get the index of the row with highest w, the one to drop
        idx = dfg[dfg['w'] == dfg['w'].max()].index
        rows_to_drop.append(idx[0])

# drop the rows
df = df.drop(index=rows_to_drop)
```

However, the code feels cumbersome. I'm for instance adding a temporary column, w, just to hold the value to compare with.

I would appreciate suggestions how to improve this.

Comment: Why not `groupby` the columns that are duplicated and just aggregate and take `first`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [`groupby.idxmin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.idxmin.html):

```
out = df.loc[w.groupby([df['t1'], df['t2']]).idxmin()]
```

Output:

```
   t1  t2     x     y     z  n     m     c
0   1   1  1.01  0.23  0.06  6  0.21  64.4
2   1   2  1.01  0.06  0.12  7  0.81  63.2
3   1   3  0.45  1.12  0.20  6  1.18  65.6
4   1   4  0.89  0.70  0.62  7  0.28  63.2
```

Or, if you also want to have `w` in the output:

```
df['w'] = w

out = df.loc[df.groupby(['t1', 't2'])['w'].idxmin()]
```

Output:

```
   t1  t2     x     y     z  n     m     c         w
0   1   1  1.01  0.23  0.06  6  0.21  64.4  1.091733
2   1   2  1.01  0.06  0.12  7  0.81  63.2  1.317105
3   1   3  0.45  1.12  0.20  6  1.18  65.6  1.649219
4   1   4  0.89  0.70  0.62  7  0.28  63.2  1.014248
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not worry about the order then you can do

```
df_result = df.sort_values('w').drop_duplicates(subset=['t1', 't2'], keep='first')
```

If you want to preserve the order then

```
# sorting df and storing in another variable
df_sorted = df.sort_values('w')

# find duplicate rows for required columns
mask_duplicates = ~df_sorted.duplicated(subset=['t1', 't2'], keep='first')

# apply the mask to remove duplicate rows
df_result = df_sorted[mask_duplicates]

# Sorting on index to get original order
df = df_result.sort_index()
```